# Why measuring a liquid volume from the bottom of the meniscus isn't considered an underestimation?

Tags: measurements

I know from my OL chemistry and physics classes that the reading of a liquid volume should always be taken from the bottom of the meniscus, but isn't this an underestimation of the real volume. I mean there's some water sticking upward to the surface of the container and, say, if these water fell and made a flat surface they would add to the volume of water.

[image]

I realize that if we try to take the reading from the highest point the liquid reached this would be an overestimation so I was wandering if measuring from a point that's between the meniscus and the highest point the liquid reached would be more accurate.

Comment: I don't *know* the answer, but it would be fairly hard to standardise a "somewhere in the middle of the meniscus" point of measurement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markings on volumetric glassware are already calibrated to account for the volume above the meniscus*. The location of the mark on the glass is where the bottom of the meniscus should be in order to have the "true" volume be what's marked. So by measuring from the bottom of the meniscus, you're synchronizing your measurement procedure with the procedure of the people who originally calibrated the markings on the glass.

*For volumetric flasks where this kind of precision is very important, they are usually calibrated for a specific solution with a specific meniscus height. Otherwise, the general assumption, as far as I can tell, is that your solution will have a vaguely similar surface tension to water, with a vaguely similar meniscus height. For example, calibration of general graduated cylinders is often done with distilled water. Typically the error introduced by the difference in meniscus height is not the dominant source of measurement error, so this is often ignored. In cases where you're using something with a very different surface tension than water, and precision to that level actually matters, explicit calibration is usually recommended.

---

As an aside, while researching this answer, I came across the following entertaining scenario on the official USGS Water Science School site:

> In your high-school chemistry final exam you mistakenly read a meniscus as 72 milliliters (ml) instead of the correct 66 ml (in this picture), and thus you get an 89 on the test instead of a 90. Your GPA falls from 4.00 to 3.99 and you don't get into that engineering college program you wanted. Consequently, you don't get that prestigious engineering job, where, 20 years later, you would have invented a new water-based chemical to allow rubber to grip better. Sadly, 10 years later, a mother and her adorable 4-year old daughter are leaving the ice cream store and the little girl, whose shoes don't have your un-invented coating, slips on a napkin and drops her ice cream cone. She cries at her loss ... because you misread the meniscus in the 12th grade.

> The moral of this fictional tale is that it is important to read the measurement correctly, and yes, in the picture (top right) the true volume in the graduated cylinder is at the bottom of the water level—21.7 milliliters, not 21.9.